# Handling errors 404/500 in Django

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

There is a little problem with my Django application: my project is a blog with several posts. You can access the first post by typing `localhost:8000/blog/post/1` in the URL bar. To read the post no. X you have to type `localhost:8000/blog/post/X`. So I need to display a custom "Error 404" page when an inexistant post is requested (for example `localhost:8000/blog/post/32` if there are only 3 posts available). The problem is, instead of throwing a 404 error, it throws a **Server Error (500)** error however I never coded something to throw this kind of error.
Here is the concerned code parts, but not my full code which I think is useless.
*Project name is `red_pillers`, app name is `blog`.*

**in red_pillers/settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

**red_pillers/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.conf.urls import handler404

from . import views

handler404 = 'red_pillers.views.handler404'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    re_path('^$', views.home),
    re_path('^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**red_pillers/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def handler404(request):
    return render(request, 'errors/404.html', {}, status=404)
```

**blog/pycode/post.py**

```
from django.http import Http404

class Post:

    POSTS = [
        {'id': 1, 'title': 'First Post', 'body': 'This is my first post'},
        {'id': 2, 'title': 'Second Post', 'body': 'This is my second post'},
        {'id': 3, 'title': 'Third Post', 'body': 'This is my third post'},
    ]

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        return cls.POSTS

    @classmethod
    def find(cls, id):
        try:
            return cls.POSTS[int(id) - 1]
        except:
            raise Http404('Error 404...')
```

EDIT: added more code

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^$', views.index),
    re_path('^posts/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.show),
]
```

**blog/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .pycode.post import Post

def index(request):
    posts = Post.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts': posts})


def show(request, id):
    post = Post.find(id)
    return render(request, 'blog/show.html', {'post': post})
```

Comment: if you have a 500 error, show us the full error trace. you get a 500 error if your code encounters a python error. Note that your `home` view doesn't do anything except rendering home.html (it doesn't use `Post`), so unless there's a strange template tag in home.html, it can't raise an error. You're not showing us any relevant code because none of the code you show us here as anything to do with fetching the url /blog/post/32.

Comment: I added more code, can you take a look please?

Comment: And how can I show you the full error trace ? there is nothing in the terminal...

Comment: Where you did `manage.py runserver` you should see detailed error logs.

Comment: Just `[30/Mar/2019 15:55:45] "GET /blog/posts/4 HTTP/1.1" 500 27`

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), which will redirect you if it doesn't exist.

Comment: where do I need to put this ?

Comment: You should import it wherever you want to access a record.If you click the link there is an example there.

Comment: this is for fetching objects from the database, which apparently you're not doing as it seems you're hard-coding your Posts in the code itself (I would strongly advise against doing that, but that's not related to this question)

Comment: @dirkgroten I kind of assumed that was some simplification for the purposes of this question, but maybe not ...